# Utility which gives line from /proc/id/maps by specific address

Tags: linux, text-processing, memory, proc

Is there an utility that gives me specific line from `/proc/id/maps` when given specific address from this process?

For example when given `0x7fb4a84f6008` it returns:

```
7fb4a84f6000-7fb4a84fd000 r-xp 00000000 00:48 20132    /lib64/libnss_compat-2.21.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `pmap` does what you want:

```
$ sudo pmap -Ab75bf022 26746
26746:   dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth5.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth5.leases eth5
b75bf000      4K rw--- ld-2.19.so
 total        4K
```

Or with a address range and full path:

```
$ sudo pmap -p -Ab75bf022,b77bf022 26746
26746:   dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth5.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth5.leases eth5
b75bf000      4K rw--- /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
b75c0000   1732K r-x-- /sbin/dhclient
b7771000      4K r---- /sbin/dhclient
b7772000     12K rw--- /sbin/dhclient
b7775000     44K rw---   [ anon ]
 total     1796K
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` do do this:

```
awk -F'[ -]' -v s=7fb4a84f6008 '$1<=s&&s<$2' /proc/id/maps
```

assuming you can give the searched address (after `s=`) in the same format as it appears in `maps` (without `0x` and having the same length).